# Get Audio(Android) focus using Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am trying to implement 'Audio focus' delphi app:

```
TOnAudioFocusChange = procedure(focusChange: System.Integer) of object;
  TmyJAudioManagerListener = class(TJavaLocal, JAudioManager_OnAudioFocusChangeListener)
  private
    FOnAudioFocusChange : TOnAudioFocusChange;
  public
    Constructor Create;
    Destructor Destroy; Override;
    property myOnAudioFocusChange : TOnAudioFocusChange read FOnAudioFocusChange write FOnAudioFocusChange;
    procedure onAudioFocusChange(focusChange: System.Integer); cdecl;
  end;
```

Where am I going wrong?
I need to do this:
http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html